# CSS scale and centre image within scrollable container without cropping

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'd like to zoom an image so that the user can scroll around it after the zoom.
The following example works well but I have to set the origin to top left as otherwise the image is cropped to the top and left. Is there anyway to scale to the centre of the image (as happens when I omit the transform-origin) but without cropping?

Please note I'm using scale because the image will have an associated image map so I can't just set the width and height.

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#pic {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500" >
</div>
```

Comment: After many hours of trying to find a CSS solution I ended up keeping the ```transform-origin: top left``` and using JS to reposition the image using ```Element.scroll()``` after scaling. This looks ok if the transition is not animated.

Answer (score 0):

This code right here, fixes is to top right, with `position:absolute;`

```css
#container {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#pic {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
<div id="container">
  <img id="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500" >
</div>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500" >
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this helps. I want to centre the zoomed image.

Comment: @Unstableair edited

Comment: Rather than placing the image at the centre of the screen I want the image to scale so that the centre of the image (the dogs nose in this case) is at the centre of the scaled up image. I can get this effect by removing the transform-origin but if I do that the image becomes clipped and will only scroll to the right and down.